# REGEX MySQL/ PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I have sort out some locations in MySQL. I can do it either on Python(i know it more than MySQL) but i would preffer MySQL solution.
I would like to filter some locations as example:

```
    "        belfast   " - matches - OK
    " .. .,,,,.belfast  "- matches - OK
    "Belfast"-matches - OK
    "BELFAST" -matches - OK
    "UK-BELFAST" does not match- OK
    "Belfast, London" or "        Belfast, anything" should not match but matches for me - ERROR
```

.How to avoid matching "Belfast, London"? 
Please help. Thanks.
code:

```
case insensitive

^([^0-9a-zA-Z]*belfast[^0-9a-zA-Z]*)
```

I would like to use this in Python regex or MySQL(preffered).

Comment: Do note that `REGEXP`(the MySQL regex) isn't exactly known for good performance, so, if possible do it on the Python side of things rather than the MySQL side.

Comment: my fault, very sorry Epodax for bothering You.

Answer (score 0):

This regex with insensitive option respect your use case : `.*belfast\s*$`

E.g :

```python
import re
p = re.compile(r'.*belfast\s*$', re.IGNORECASE)
str = 'Belfast, London'

print(re.search(regex, str))
# output : None
```